# JavaScript's replace-function combined with document.create() - What does this code?

Tags: javascript

I've seen these code snippet in the source-code of a web-page by somebody else:

```
<script>
"'article aside footer header nav section video'".replace(
     /\w+/g,
     function(n){
        document.createElement(n)
     }
 )
 </script>
```

Has anyone an idea what's the intention with that?

7 HTML-elements are made based upon the string as an input. 
createElement returns a references to the elements. But nothing is done with that reference. It's not even stored in some variable. Much less attached to the DOM-tree.

So: 
What shall the purpose of these code be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a kinda "smart" way to iterate a list of words:

```js
"'article aside footer header nav section video'".replace(
     /\w+/g, 
    function(w) { document.write(w + "<br>") }
  )
```

Most probably the author took this route because the list of tags comes from some external source. Otherwise they should have used normal arrays.

```js
tags = ["article", "aside", "footer", "header", "nav", "section", "video"]

tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    document.createElement(tag);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In you're first example it makes something like: "article<br> aside<br> footer<br> header<br> nav<br> section<br> video<br>" . What I still find hard to imagine: Why is it that added to the HTML-document automatically? It's still just a string living in RAM.

Comment: @ts248: `document.write` is just to demonstrate how iteration works. It's not intended to create anything.